# the AppBarLayout doesn't collapse when scrolling

Tags: android-layout

When I put the  AppBarLayout and a relativeLayout between LinearLayout ,it doesn't collapse when scrolling

I need the relativeLayout replace it from another activity and if i don't put them between linearLayout, when i replace the relativeLayout with the new layout , the new one will appear on the appBar not under it

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_replace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```